# How to set background default color in fish shell?

Tags: fish, iterm2, oh-my-fish

Specifically, I want to set the default background color to "Solarized Dark" in my fish shell for Iterm2.

Currently, I have to manually change the background every time I start my fish shell using `CMD + I`:
[image: Manually setting background with CMD + I]

**Is there anyway to set this such that the settings are saved?**

My fish_variables file looks like this now:

```
# This file contains fish universal variable definitions.
# VERSION: 3.0
SETUVAR __fish_initialized:3400
SETUVAR fish_color_autosuggestion:586e75
SETUVAR fish_color_cancel:\x2d\x2dreverse
SETUVAR fish_color_command:93a1a1
SETUVAR fish_color_comment:586e75
SETUVAR fish_color_cwd:green
SETUVAR fish_color_cwd_root:red
SETUVAR fish_color_end:268bd2
SETUVAR fish_color_error:dc322f
SETUVAR fish_color_escape:00a6b2
SETUVAR fish_color_history_current:\x2d\x2dbold
SETUVAR fish_color_host:normal
SETUVAR fish_color_host_remote:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_color_keyword:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_color_match:\x2d\x2dbackground\x3dbrblue
SETUVAR fish_color_normal:normal
SETUVAR fish_color_operator:00a6b2
SETUVAR fish_color_option:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_color_param:839496
SETUVAR fish_color_quote:657b83
SETUVAR fish_color_redirection:6c71c4
SETUVAR fish_color_search_match:bryellow\x1e\x2d\x2dbackground\x3dblack
SETUVAR fish_color_selection:white\x1e\x2d\x2dbold\x1e\x2d\x2dbackground\x3dbrblack
SETUVAR fish_color_status:red
SETUVAR fish_color_user:brgreen
SETUVAR fish_color_valid_path:\x2d\x2dunderline
SETUVAR fish_key_bindings:fish_default_key_bindings
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_background:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_completion:B3A06D
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_description:B3A06D
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_prefix:cyan\x1e\x2d\x2dunderline
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_progress:brwhite\x1e\x2d\x2dbackground\x3dcyan
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_secondary_background:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_secondary_completion:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_secondary_description:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_secondary_prefix:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_selected_background:\x2d\x2dbackground\x3dbrblack
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_selected_completion:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_selected_description:\x1d
SETUVAR fish_pager_color_selected_prefix:\x1d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the colors in your session preferences (via <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), save them as the profile preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and choose Profiles). If you don't want to use this for all your terminal shell sessions, you can create a new profile which also starts fish by changing the Command in the General profile preferences.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to tell the terminal to set the background color, so fish has no support to tell the terminal to set the background color.

You'll have to set it in your terminal.